# What's the limit to project size Visual Studio IDE can handle?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio stores "projects" in XML (.vcproj files). In my experience as more and more files are added to the project and as more and more projects are added to a solution opening a solution in IDE takes longer and longer.

Is there a limit to the number of files or to project tree complexity or to some other characteristic of Visual Studio projects and solutions after which typical operations on a project becomes unreasonably slow (or maybe even impossible)?

Comment: Currently working with 80+ projects in Visual Studio 2008. Only complain is the time taken to `build solution` (which does not happen frequently) is around 10-15 minutes on quad core Xeon!

Answer (score 1):

There is no realistic limit to the number of projects that you can have in Visual Studio 2008.  I have worked with dozens in a single solution and I would imagine that the actual limit would be in the thousands (or more).

You could combat performance issues with an SSD hard drive, multiple processors and a boat load of memory, but you should really consider breaking out the solution and just referencing the assemblies of the upstream projects.  Yes, if you have a single solution it makes it easier to debug, but you are costing yourself many many hours of waiting while waiting for the solution to open up and compile.